# How can I pass information to a php script called with header()?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a problem when running a php script, calling a second script using *header()*.

The main script (a.php) calls, while running, a second script (b.php).

When using this form all goes as expected (ActionA and ActionB are performed):

```
https://example.com/a.php
```

When using this other form, the expected behavior (ActionAX and ActionBX) is not taking place. Instead ActionAX and ActionB are performed:

```
https://example.com/a.php?V=X
```

In other words b.php does not get the *V=X* bit of information.

The file a.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=UTF-8">
<TITLE>MyWebApp</TITLE>
<STYLE>
INPUT[type='Submit'] {font-size: 19px;}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#A1E3D2">

<?php
session_start();
.....
function getVarStr()
{/* Beginning of getVarStr */
if ($_GET['V'] == 'X') performActionAX();
else  performActionA();
}/* End of getVarStr */
.....
getVarStr();
.....
if ($_GET['V'] == 'X') header("Location: ./b.php?V=X");
header("Location: ./b.php");
.....
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The file b.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1">
        <title>Extra Page</title>
        <STYLE>
                INPUT[type='Submit'] {font-size: 19px;}
        </STYLE>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
.....
function getVarStr()
{/* Beginning of getVarStr */
if ($_GET['V'] == 'X') performActionBX();
else  performActionB();
}/* End of getVarStr */
.....
getVarStr();
.....
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can anyone point out a mistake I am making ?

I have also tried to handle the issue using session variables, but I hit exactly the same problem.

I this case I change the getVarStr() inside b.php to:

```
function getVarStr()
{/* Beginning of getVarStr */
if ($_SESSION['V'] == 'X') performActionBX();
else  performActionB();
}/* End of getVarStr */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *"php script called with header()"* you're refering to the `header("Location....` line in your code, then you have quite an incorrect picture of what really goes on here.

The location header is simply a string added to the http response; `header()` does more or less the same as `echo`, except it is intended to happen earlier on, prior to any of the http replys' body being written (more on that later).

---

Functionally, what the *Location* header *really* does, is simply let the users web browser know, that you would like them to visit another page/url instead, which (under most circumstances) it will comply with. It is not unlike sending a

```
   <script> window.location = 'https://....';</script>
```

within your html reply; except the http header doesn't rely on java-script being enabled.

---

Now, the actual problem is the way you've structured your code. You cannot have written **any** output, before you attempt to add a header to the http reply. Doing so prevents PHP from being allowed/able to add that header.

Both your `header()` **and** `session_start()` (which indirectly also uses `header()` to place a cookie), are located too far down in your code to function properly.

Infact, in both your `a.php` and `b.php` files, the very first lines (`<!DOCTYPE...`) already produce output, which is a big no-no.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Does that mean I need to put this header("Location: ....."); line at the very beginning of my source code. I must admit I have almost never used this header("Location: .....") thing and don't understand very much how it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're asking if you should literally add that ? no. That line was just an abbreviation of the line(s) you're already using (only in the wrong place).

Comment: OK. Then my question is: Where is the right place?

Comment: The easiest fixed is to stop inlining html in your php files. That basically means: anything **outside*** of the `<?php     ?>` blocks, is bad. Right at the top; from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `<body>`; that should all be taken away and placed somewhere else.

Comment: You cannot be producing any content prior to having performed your header/session functions. So besides the inlined html. that also means any `echo`/`print`/`printf`/`var_dump` etc function cannot come before the `header` & `session_start`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you call "header/session functions" ? I see only one function: getVarStr().

Comment: The function calls that literally say header, like `header("Location: ./b.php");` and `session_start();`

Comment: All right, so if I bring the header/session functions at the very top of the file. That should probably solve my problem? Am I right?

Comment: Something must  still be missing. I am now performing my header/session functions at the very beginning of the a.php file. But ActionBX is still not taking place (only ActionB is happening).

Comment: After many trials and errors, I noticed (using isset) that $_GET['V'] is not set when executing header(), though I pass it in the URL. I don't know why that is. If I use header("Location: ./b.php?V=X") on the other hand (independently of $_GET['V']) then b.php behaves properly (performing actionBX). But at the end it has to depend on V passed to a.php or not. So I am still working on it.

Comment: `$_GET` is incoming only, for the http request you're working on. Changing anything in there wouldn't have any effect anywhere else. writing the query string within the location header directive like  `header("Location: ./b.php?V=X")` changes the url you're asking them to visit, so that will result in that value being set in `$_GET` on that other request (because its the client sending it). But the way you see the relationship between the 2 pages/requests still sounds very odd to me.

Comment: I needed to to have the info from the get in order to know how to set the header(....) part. That's all. I know $_GET is incoming only. Anyway I figured out what was wrong in what I did. Thanks to your valuable tips and help. I am accepting your answer, you gave me a precious help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

always put php source above html specially if they modify cookies or session to prevent encountering "Warning: Cannot Modify Header Information – Header Already Sent" issue also you might as well put this anywhere so you know the data you applying are actually being applied

```
echo "SESSION NAME: " . session_name();
echo "<br>";
echo "SESSION ID: " . session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo "TIME: " . time();
```